# qtCreator error: can't map file, errno=22 file for architecture x86_64?

Tags: c++, matlab, linker, qt-creator, mat

I am trying to read a .mat file for Qtcreator cpp program. I need to include the `mat.h` file.  In the .pro file, I add the following paths:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include
DEPENDPATH += /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include
LIBS += /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include
```

Then I got an error for `:-1: error: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/include' for architecture x86_64`

I already see this post [can't map file, errno=22 for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436333/cant-map-file-errno-22-for-architecture-x86-64). They say it's because missing a preceding `-I` to state that you search in this directory. I do not know how to do this in QtCreator, hope someone could help

Answer (score 1):

`LIBS` should list *libraries* and not paths, especially not paths to header files.

You get the error because you pass a directory and not a file, directories can't be treated as files everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So I need to add a lib for LIBS parameter. Could you please be in more detailed to help me set the LIBS? Here under path  '/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/extern/lib/maci64/' there are only 3 maps file with format .map, In this situation, how to set the LIBS?

Comment: @printemp Maybe you don't need to add a "lib" file, maybe it's a header-only library? I just don't know anything about Matlab and its interfaces and libraries.

Comment: If I do not add LIBS, it will have the :-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error.... Anyway, thx a lot. I will try to struggle on this for  more time.........